# Remove all purgeable space?

Tags: hard-drive, macos, disk-space

well the issue is that I use to have ~20gb free in my disk, after updating and removing around <s>30gb</s> a lot of things, I still have 20gb free in the disk and still says it only has ~20gb free in reality it has over "70gb" free...

Is there a way to remove all that purgeable storage to make my disk free for real?

[image]

Adding terminal output for **df -h**

```
df -h
Filesystem                          Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1                         112Gi   92Gi   20Gi    83% 1813713 4293153566    0%   /
devfs                              189Ki  189Ki    0Bi   100%     654          0  100%   /dev
map -hosts                           0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /net
map auto_home                        0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /home
localhost:/5I0YkoOMEg7twG3LdoPIRF  112Gi  112Gi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /Volumes/MobileBackups
```

Comment: 20 + 30 = 50. Where are you getting 70?

Comment: @tubedogg where my math went....

Comment: Your screen capture shows 76 GB free. What gives you the different information that you still have only 20 GB free?

Comment: @fsb: yes it is the same question, but the accepted answer isn't... good enough.

Comment: There's no way to remove the 'purgeable' space.  When the OS needs the space, it will be reclaimed.  See [this Apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206996) article about Optimized Storage.

Comment: @danielAzuelos I see 20gb free in the terminal :S

Comment: Let's improve the answers on the existing question instead of opening a new thread.

Comment: @patrix the existing one did not have any details, the responses were dead wrong... is better t start fresh when something is wrong.

Comment: In this case please edit the original questions to add details, which will automatically get the question back on the front page. The answers you got below aren't that good either, so improving the existing question is the better way to go.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com) ? It shows graphically where your space is being used and can help in cleaning up. I use it a lot.

Comment: That is wrong, being able to have a graphical interface doesnt mean it knows what files apple does consider deletable. In the other hand if you start deleting files you end up with a lot disk errors because that app do not remove the pointer to the files